# ZipArchive class is missing on your server. Please contact your web hosting provider and ask them to install and activate ZipArchive

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I installed wp all export plugin in my wordpress website but It doesn't work on my server, I don't know why, the problem is apparently due to ziparchive missing on my server.

ERROR MESSAGE:

[image]

I am on a VPS server from digital ocean running on a CENTOS 7 System, I have done some checking to see I had zip archive installed or not and it seems that I do :

```
[root@server ~]# rpm -q zip unzip
zip-3.0-11.el7.x86_64
unzip-6.0-22.el7_9.x86_64
[root@server ~]# yum install zip unzip

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirrors.vinters.com
* epel: mirrors.coreix.net
* extras: mirrors.coreix.net
* remi: mirror.netweaver.uk
* remi-php55: mirror.netweaver.uk
* remi-php56: mirror.netweaver.uk
* remi-safe: mirror.netweaver.uk
* remi-test: mirror.netweaver.uk
* updates: mirror.pulsant.com
vesta                                                                        | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
Package zip-3.0-11.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package unzip-6.0-22.el7_9.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

And I have php 7 installed on my server

```
[root@server ~]# php --version
PHP 7.4.23 (cli) (built: Aug 24 2021 16:33:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v10.4.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.23, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
Contract
```

Someone asked to the maker of this plugin about the exact same issue, but they did not help

WP ALL IMPORT RESPONSE:

[image]

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

Comment: that did not help

Comment: You're installing the wrong things. `yum install zip unzip` doesn't do anything to PHP. You're going to need to search available packages for a PHP Zip package (something like `yum search zip |grep -i php`), or do `pecl install zip`.

Answer (score 1):

You configuration doesn't seems consistent, you have remi-php55 (for PHP 5.5) and remi-php56 (for PHP 5.6) enabled but, you are running PHP 7.4

For a proper configuration, I recommend you follow the [wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

In short:

```
yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
yum-config-manager --enable   remi-php74
yum install php-zip
```